# Links apps in Docker Swarm Mode

Tags: php, mysql, docker, drupal, docker-swarm-mode

I would like to know how do we link webapp to database in docker swarm mode. I'm very new to docker swarm mode and had a basic cluster setup on my local machine. Any links would be great.

Example: Hosting a drupal application (Connected drupal cms containers with mysql database container).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Correct, using custom networks is the way forward. A very simple example to get you started;

Create an "overlay" network (overlay networks allow containers to communicate, even if they are running on different nodes in the swarm);

```
docker network create --driver=overlay my-network
```

Create a database service named `my-db`, and attach it to the `my-network` network. There is no need to "publish" the database port, because drupal will connect with the database over the `my-network` network. Only publish database-ports if you want the database to be publicly accessible.

```
docker service create \
    --name=my-db \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=topsecret \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal\
    -e MYSQL_USER=drupal-user \
    -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret \
    --network=my-network \
    mysql:5.7
```

Create a drupal service (named `mysite`), and also attach it to the same network. Publish the site's ports, because you want it to be publicly accessible

```
docker service create \
    --name=mysite \
    --network=my-network \
    --publish=8080:80 \
    drupal:8.2-apache
```

After the services are created, and the containers are running (you can check the status with `docker service ls`), you can visit `<host-ip>:8080` in your browser. In swarm mode, `<host-ip>` can be the IP-address of *any* host in your swarm. The "routing mesh" will automatically route the network connection to the node that a container runs on.

Now, to configure drupal, using the username/password you set in `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD`, and using `my-db` as hostname for the database (under advanced options) - when using docker networks, you can connect to other services on the same network through their name.

[image: drupal configuration]

This is just a very quick example. Some things to look into are;

- Volumes (save uploads, and user-data in a volume, so that the information can persist when updating your container)
- Secrets; passing username and password as environment variables is insecure. Docker 1.13 will introduce `docker secrets`, which allow you to pass the database credentials in a more secure way. Documentation is not live yet, but you can [find them on GitHub](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/2c26e6a53461bcb4e0a9ebeb7d918e0c599c0872/engine/swarm/secrets.md)

Answer (score 2):

using Links in docker is apparently more of a legacy why to connect to containers (although i still use this method myself)

The "new" way to do it is to use docker networks, you can read more about it here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/

Hope this helps